# Understanding Docker overlay network

Tags: docker, consul, docker-network

I am using an overlay network to deploy an application on multiple VMs on the same LAN. I am using `nginx` as the front end for this application and this is running on `host_1`. All the containers that are part of the application are communicating with each other without any issues. But HTTP requests to the published port 80 of the `nginx` container (mapped to port 8080 on `host_1`) from a different VM on the same LAN, say `host_2`, time out[1]. But HTTP requests to `localhost:8080` on `host_1` succeed[2]. If I start the `nginx` container by removing the overlay network, I am able to send HTTP requests[3].

1. Output of `curl -vvv <host_1 IP>:8080` on `host_2`.

> ubuntu@host_2:~$ curl -vvv <host_1>:8080
>
> - Rebuilt URL to: <host_1 IP>:8080/
> - Trying <host_1 IP>...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - connect to <host_1 IP> port 8080 failed: Connection timed out
> - Failed to connect to <host_1 IP> port 8080: Connection timed out
> - Closing connection 0 curl: (7) Failed to connect to <host_1 IP> port 8080: Connection timed out

2. Output of `curl localhost:8080 on host_1`.

> nginx welcome page

3. Output of `curl -vvv <host_1 IP>:8080` on `host_2` when I recreate the container without the overlay network

> nginx welcome page

The `docker-compose` file for the front end is as below:

```
version: '3'
  nginx-frontend:
    hostname: nginx-frontend
    image: nginx
    ports: ['8080:80']
    restart: always
networks:
  default:
    external: {name: overlay-network}
```

I checked that the nginx and the host are listening on `0.0.0.0:80` and `0.0.0.0:8080` respectively.

Since the port 80 of the `nginx` is published by mapping it to port `8080` of the host, I should be able to send HTTP requests from any VM that is on the same LAN as the host of this container. Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong or where my assumptions are wrong?